# Error 2038 during installation of Adobe AIR

Tags: mac, installation, adobe-air

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6, and I have been unable to install the latest Adobe AIR due to this error.

```
Exiting due to error: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2038" errorID=2038]
```

I looked up 2038, and it appears to be a permissions issue, but I don't know which folder it's looking to get permissions for.

Comment: If you think it's a permissions issue, did you try using Disk Utility's "Repair Permissions" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by following the instructions on [Adobe's Troubleshooting page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403150.html#main_probs-macos).